# Objective-C - Expression is not an integer constant expression

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got this error message when trying to do switch.

```
/Users/xxxxx/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/main.m:83:14: Expression is not an integer constant expression
```

My code

```
char *anotherCharacter = "a";
        switch (*anotherCharacter) {
        case "a":
                NSLog(@"The letter a");
        case "A":
                NSLog(@"The letter A");
        default:
                NSLog(@"Not the letter A");
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `"a"` to `'a'` and `"A"` to `'A'` respectively. `'a'` is an integer type actually while `"a"` is a string

Answer (score 1):

the switch statement in Objective-C considers only integer values